# Pointer to a class and function - problem

Tags: c++, oop, class-design

Firstly I'll show you few classes.

```
class A {
public:
    B * something;

    void callSomething(void) {
        something->call();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A * activeParent;

    B(A * parent) {
        activeParent = parent;
    }

    void call(void) {
        activeParent->something = new C;
    }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    A * activeParent;

    C(A * parent) {
        activeParent = parent;
    }

    void call(void) {
        // do something
    }
};


A * object;
object = new A;
object->something = new B;
object->callSomething();
```

My app needs such a structure.
When I do callSomething(), it calls B's call() but when B's call() changes the "something" to C, C's call() is triggered and I want to avoid that. How should I do?

Comment: In the class B you make `activeParent->something = new C;` but activeParent is of type A*. This must result in a compiler error.

Comment: Why would your application need such a structure? What are you doing?

Comment: ActiveParent is of type A*, but activeParent->something is of type B*.  Therefore, it will not result in a compiler error.

Comment: Could you give a little more context into the problem you are trying to solve?  The fact that A "has a" B and B "has a" A is already problematic.  Also your C class inherits from B and immediately shadows the activeParent member variable in A.  This is not going to do what you expect.

If you provide a little more context as to the problem you are trying to solve we can help you out.

Comment: I'm making classes for in game dialogs. Such a dialog is assigned to a player (class A). Then I create some dialog (class B or C) and display it for the player, then if the player responses, Player's onResponse() (B->call(), C->call()) is called. And sometimes I want to create a new dialog when I get response and replace the old one with a new one.

Comment: Nick: The recursive relationship isn't the problem here, and is common with parent links.

Comment: Balon: Your question is still rather vague and confusing.  If you could include more specifics in the example, without making it too complicated, you'll probably get better help.

Comment: Please post a working example. This is probably straightforward, but the code you posted is to contrived to make heads or tails of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the design decisions (e.g., cyclical dependencies)...

The only reason A's callSomething() method would call C's call() method from a pointer to B is if the call() method is virtual.  To avoid calling C's call() method, here are a couple of options:

- Don't make the call() method virtual
- Rename one of B or C's call() method (preferred over the first option)
- Call B's call() method explicitly

To call B's call() method explicitly:

```
void callSomething(void) {
    something->B::call();
}
```

Comment: I need to have call() in all classes that inherit from B. So lets say that I have classes D, E, F. D inherits from B, E too and F inherits from E and I need a common way to call the call(). So first and last options won't help me and nor second one as I need common name of function. Anyway thanks for your answer and I hope that you can help me somehow!

Comment: Hmmm but third option would be useful if..
`something->B::call();`
B could be that class what `something` is at the moment.

Comment: Do you only ever want to call B's version of the call() method for all instances of a B pointer (whether it's a B, C, D, E, or F)?  Or do you just not want to call C's call() method if something is a C object?  And is this special behavior only desired for A's call from callSomething(), or all calls to the call() method?

Comment: `And is this special behavior only desired for A's call from callSomething()` yes. I want to be able to call the call() method with one restricton. If `A->something` is a C class, I want to call only C's call method(), if it is B class so I want to call only B's call method(). I've written in my question what happens right now with actual way of calling call() method.

Comment: The problem is here. `void callSomething(void) { something->call(); }` and explicit call would solve this, but something can be whatever so.. I can't actually call it explicitly...

Comment: I think I now know what you are asking for.

Let me restate the problem: with your current code, it always calls class B's call() method, even if the something pointer (B*) is pointing to a C object. And what you really want is for callSomething() to call B's call() if something is pointing to a B object, C's call() if it is pointing to a C object, etc.  

Solution: mark the call() method virtual in the base class (B), i.e. "virtual void call() { ... }", and something->call() will dispatch to C's call() method (if something is pointing to a C object).

Comment: Exactly. It is already virtual in my code, but the problem appears when `something` changes during call(). If `something` is `B` and during `something->call()` I change `something` to `C`, then C's call() is called and I don't want it to.